# Robot Framework: How to find the version of the installed robot in my machine?

Tags: robotframework

I have installed my robot in my local machine long time back and now I want to check the version on the installed Robot. I tried the command `pybot --help`
and it gave me the result

```
'Version:  3.0 (Python 2.7.9 on win32)'
```

Is my current robot version 3?

Comment: This question can be answered by reading the user guide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. You can also execute `robot --version`.

See: [Verifying Installation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.0/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#verifying-installation).

Comment: alternatively you can execute pip to get list of packages which will also show version: pip list ,or in details: pip show robotframework

Answer (score 9):

I assume you use pip as a python package manager, so just try:

```
pip show robotframework
```

and you should get something like that:

```
Name: robotframework
Version: 3.0.2
Summary: A generic test automation framework
Home-page: http://robotframework.org
Author: Robot Framework Developers
Author-email: robotframework@gmail.com
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

Comment: Thanks! "pybot --help" and "robot --version" does not work for me. This one does as of RF version 4.1.3 and Python 3.10.2